# WCF Rest making a http request: sequence closed due to authentication error

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api, wcf

my WCF Rest makes a request to another Rest Api, but it returns the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: Connection is terminated: Unexpected sending
>   error. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the
>   remote party closed the transport stream. \ R \ n in
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame (Byte [] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) \ r \ n in
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob (Byte [] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) \ r \ n in
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive
>   (ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) \ r \ n in
>   System. Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob (Byte [] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) \ r \ n in
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication (Boolean
>   receiveFirst, Byte [] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) \ r \
>   n System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication (LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult) \ r \ n in System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication
>   (Object state) \ r \ n in
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state , B oolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) \ r \ n in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object
>   state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) \ r \ n in
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) \ r \ n in
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication (LazyAsyncResult result) \
>   r \ n in System.Net.TlsStream.Write (Byte [] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) \ r \ n in System.Net.PooledStream .Write (Byte [] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size) \ r \ n in
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders (Boolean async) \ r \ n --- End
>   of stack trace of internal exception --- \ r \ n in
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal (Uri address, String method,
>   Byte [] data, WebRequest & request) \ r \ n in
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadString (Uri address, String method, String
>   data) \ r \ n in BS.Control.Save.Send (String body, String to)

where I have the functions is in a library c # called BS, in the, class "Send", and in this I do this:

the

```
json= {"user":"test","pass":"12345","message":"test 1","number":"12345678"}

using (var WC = new WebClient())
{
    JObject response = new JObject();
    ResponseD Result = new ResponseD();
    try
    {
        WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,"Bearer MyCode");
        WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType,"application/json");
        string baseurl = "url-where receive the post";
        response = JObject.Parse(WC.UploadString(new Uri(baseurl), "POST", json));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Result.id = "Error";
        Result.result = ex.ToString();
    }  
}
```

This Exception is present in my local PC, in my IIS server and even in an Azure APPservice .... in my IIS server I configured an SSL to where I have the WCF, but with SSL my WCF continues with the same problem and does not send response...

i was make a console application where i use the same library as my WCF Rest and in this there are no problems, the "response = JObject.Parse (WC.UploadString (new Uri (baseurl)," POST ", json));" Receive answer without problems .... recive a beautiful Json with the information of the id assigned to the request, time issued among other things, but this the only thing I need is the ID and from a ConsoleApp Everything works well ....

The Json of response is:

```
{
"id": "Error",
    "result":
 the exception mentioned above and the location in Line where the problem is located and this is where the WC.uploadstring is
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: you are missing and ending `}` for your `using() {` have you used the debugger to step thru the code..?

Comment: If I did not have it in my code, I could not have obtained the exception, I already corrected it in my query. thanks for your contribution ;)

Comment: It is not clear the difference between the code working and not working.  If the location of the difference is a different PC then check following : 1) Is the time stamp of dll same on both PCs. 2) Are the PCs same type.  There are build options like x86 and 16/32/64 bit modes where application will work on one PC and not all PCs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but as I mentioned before it was a TLS compatibility problem, the solution put it at the beginning of the consult. ;)

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

It turns out that the server where the Rest service is hosted is not compatible with TLS1.0.

So I added this code before uploadstring and it works perfectly on my IIS server.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```